Indent all paragraphs (except the first one!) with eledpar
Who knows how to indent all paragraphes in the greek and latin text, except the first one?
There're two facing pages with foot- and sidenotes (eledpar).
Thank you.
%LuaLaTex
\documentclass[a4paper,12p]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{ancientgreek}
\babelprovide[import]{polytonicgreek}
\babelprovide[import]{greek}
\babelfont[ancientgreek]{rm}{Linux Libertine O}
\babelfont[polytonicgreek]{rm}{Linux Libertine O}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,nofamiliar,noledgroup,noreledmac]{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar,hyperref}
\usepackage{metalogo}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pretolerance -1
\hbadness=10000
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}

\begin{document}
\title{Johannes von Damaskus\\
Drei Reden \textit{Über XY}}
\date{}
\maketitle

\begin{pages}
\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
 \pstart 
 \eledsection{ΛΟΓΟΣ ΠΡΩΤΟς ΕΙΣ ΤΗΝ ΚΟΙΜΗΣΙΝ}
 \pend
\pstart
\textbf{ Ἰωάννου.}\\

α'. Μνήμη, ἀληθινήν; Ἔθος ἐστὶ ἐμπορευόμενος. \\
Σπάνη\footnote{Σπάνις} γὰρ ἡμᾶς, ὡς ὁρᾶτε, κατειλήφει τῶν ἐδωδίμων. Διὸ δὴ σχεδιάζω τὴν πανδαισίαν, εἰ καὶ μὴ πολυτελῶς, μηδὲ ἀξίως τῆς κεκληκυίας, ἀλλά γε τὴν πεῖναν ἀναγκαίως δυναμένην παραμυθήσασθαι. Οὐ γὰρ αὕτη τῶν ἔγκωμίων προσδεὴς τῶν παρ᾿ ἡμῶν, ἀλλ᾿ ἡμεῖς τῆς παρ᾿ αὐτῆς δόξης ἐπιδεεῖς. Τὸ γὰρ δεδοξασμένον πῶς δοξασθήσεται;\footnote{ add. Πῶς ὁ ἥλιος λαμπρυνθήσεται;} Ἡ πηγὴ τοῦ φωτὸς, πῶς φωτισθήσεται; Ἀλλ᾿ ἡμῖν αὐτοῖς, δι᾿ ὧν δρῶμεν, πλέκομεν στέφανον. Ζῶ γὰρ ἐγώ, λέγει Κύριος, καὶ\footnote{ add. } τοὺς δοξάζοντάς με δοξάσω. \\

βʹ. Δεῦτε, πάντες νοερῶς ᾧ ἡ δόξα καὶ τὸ κράτος, σὺν τῷ ἀνάρχῳ Πατρί, καὶ τῷ παναγίῳ καὶ ζωοποιῷ Πνεύματι, νῦν, καὶ ἀεὶ, καὶ εἰς τοὺς σύμπαντας καὶ ἀτελευτήτους αἰῶ νας τῶν αἰώνων. α΄. Ἔθος ἐστὶ ἐμπορευόμενος. \\
Σπάνη\footnote{Σπάνις} γὰρ ἡμᾶς, ὡς ὁρᾶτε, κατειλήφει τῶν ἐδωδίμων. Διὸ δὴ σχεδιάζω τὴν πανδαισίαν, εἰ καὶ μὴ πολυτελῶς, μηδὲ ἀξίως τῆς κεκληκυίας, ἀλλά γε τὴν πεῖναν ἀναγκαίως δυναμένην παραμυθήσασθαι. Οὐ γὰρ αὕτη τῶν ἔγκωμίων προσδεὴς τῶν παρ᾿ ἡμῶν, ἀλλ᾿ ἡμεῖς τῆς παρ᾿ αὐτῆς δόξης ἐπιδεεῖς. Τὸ γὰρ δεδοξασμένον πῶς δοξασθήσεται; Ἡ πηγὴ τοῦ φωτὸς, πῶς φωτισθήσεται; Ἀλλ᾿ ἡμῖν αὐτοῖς, δι᾿ ὧν δρῶμεν, πλέκομεν στέφανον. Ζῶ γὰρ ἐγώ, λέγει Κύριος, καὶ τοὺς δοξάζοντάς με δοξάσω. \\

γʹ. Δεῦτε, πάντες νοερῶς ᾧ ἡ δόξα καὶ τὸ κράτος, σὺν τῷ ἀνάρχῳ Πατρί, καὶ τῷ παναγίῳ καὶ ζωοποιῷ Πνεύματι, νῦν, καὶ ἀεὶ, καὶ εἰς τοὺς σύμπαντας καὶ ἀτελευτήτους αἰῶ νας τῶν αἰώνων. Αμήν.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
 \pstart 
 \eledsection{ERSTE PREDIGT}
 \pend
\pstart
1. \ledrightnote{Prov 17,7}{„Das Gedenken der Gerechten geschieht mit Lobliedern“}, sagte der äußerst weise Salomon. „Wertvoll ist angesichts des Herrn der Tod seiner Frommen“ \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.   

At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages} 

\Pages
\begin{pages}
\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart 
\eledsection{ΛΟΓΟΣ ΔΕΥΤΕΡΟΣ}
\pend
\pstart
\textbf{Τοῦ αὐτοῦ λόγος δεύτερος.}\\

α'. Ἔστι μὲν ἀνθρώπων οὐδεὶς, πρὸς ἢν ἅπας ἵεται λόγος σοφοῦ καὶ διάνοια. Ἔθος ἐστὶ ἐμπορευόμενος. \\
Σπάνη\footnote{Σπάνις} γὰρ ἡμᾶς, ὡς ὁρᾶτε, κατειλήφει τῶν ἐδωδίμων. Διὸ δὴ σχεδιάζω τὴν πανδαισίαν, εἰ καὶ μὴ πολυτελῶς, μηδὲ ἀξίως τῆς κεκληκυίας, ἀλλά γε τὴν πεῖναν ἀναγκαίως δυναμένην παραμυθήσασθαι. Οὐ γὰρ αὕτη τῶν ἔγκωμίων προσδεὴς τῶν παρ᾿ ἡμῶν, ἀλλ᾿ ἡμεῖς τῆς παρ᾿ αὐτῆς δόξης ἐπιδεεῖς. Τὸ γὰρ δεδοξασμένον πῶς δοξασθήσεται;\footnote{ add. Πῶς ὁ ἥλιος λαμπρυνθήσεται;} Ἡ πηγὴ τοῦ φωτὸς, πῶς φωτισθήσεται; Ἀλλ᾿ ἡμῖν αὐτοῖς, δι᾿ ὧν δρῶμεν, πλέκομεν στέφανον. Ζῶ γὰρ ἐγώ, λέγει Κύριος, καὶ\footnote{ add. } τοὺς δοξάζοντάς με δοξάσω. \\

βʹ. Δεῦτε, πάντες νοερῶς ᾧ ἡ δόξα καὶ τὸ κράτος, σὺν τῷ ἀνάρχῳ Πατρί, καὶ τῷ παναγίῳ καὶ ζωοποιῷ Πνεύματι, νῦν, καὶ ἀεὶ, καὶ εἰς τοὺς σύμπαντας καὶ ἀτελευτήτους αἰῶ νας τῶν αἰώνων. 

γʹ. Δεῦτε, πάντες νοερῶς ᾧ ἡ δόξα καὶ τὸ κράτος, σὺν τῷ ἀνάρχῳ Πατρί, καὶ τῷ παναγίῳ καὶ ζωοποιῷ Πνεύματι, νῦν, καὶ ἀεὶ, καὶ εἰς τοὺς σύμπαντας καὶ ἀτελευτήτους αἰῶ νας τῶν αἰώνων. α΄. Ἔθος ἐστὶ ἐμπορευόμενος. \\
Σπάνη\footnote{Σπάνις} γὰρ ἡμᾶς, ὡς ὁρᾶτε, κατειλήφει τῶν ἐδωδίμων. Διὸ δὴ σχεδιάζω τὴν πανδαισίαν, εἰ καὶ μὴ πολυτελῶς, μηδὲ ἀξίως τῆς κεκληκυίας, ἀλλά γε τὴν πεῖναν ἀναγκαίως δυναμένην παραμυθήσασθαι. Οὐ γὰρ αὕτη τῶν ἔγκωμίων προσδεὴς τῶν παρ᾿ ἡμῶν, ἀλλ᾿ ἡμεῖς τῆς παρ᾿ αὐτῆς δόξης ἐπιδεεῖς. Τὸ γὰρ δεδοξασμένον πῶς δοξασθήσεται;\footnote{ add. Πῶς ὁ ἥλιος λαμπρυνθήσεται;} Ἡ πηγὴ τοῦ φωτὸς, πῶς φωτισθήσεται; Ἀλλ᾿ ἡμῖν αὐτοῖς, δι᾿ ὧν δρῶμεν, πλέκομεν στέφανον. Ζῶ γὰρ ἐγώ, λέγει Κύριος, καὶ\footnote{ add. } τοὺς δοξάζοντάς με δοξάσω. \\

δʹ. Δεῦτε, πάντες νοερῶς ᾧ ἡ δόξα καὶ τὸ κράτος, σὺν τῷ ἀνάρχῳ Πατρί, καὶ τῷ παναγίῳ καὶ ζωοποιῷ Πνεύματι, νῦν, καὶ ἀεὶ, καὶ εἰς τοὺς σύμπαντας καὶ ἀτελευτήτους αἰῶ νας τῶν αἰώνων. Αμήν.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
   \pstart
    \eledsection{Zweite Predigt}   
     \pend
   \pstart
1. Es gibt keinen Menschen,Gedanke des Gottweisen zustrebt. \\

\textit{Einzug der Gottesmutter in den himmlischen Tempel}\\

2. Heute wird die  ... Sich Selbst zum unumgrenzten Orte haben.\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   \\

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.  \\

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. \\
 Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages} 

\Pages
\begin{pages}
\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{Leftside}
\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}

\beginnumbering
   \pstart 
    \eledsection{ΛΟΓΟΣ ΤΡΙΤΟΣ}
    \pend
    \pstart
    \selectlanguage{greek}
\textbf{Τοῦ αὐτοῦ λόγος τρίτος.}\\

α΄. Ἔθος ἐστὶ ἐμπορευόμενος. \\
Σπάνη\footnote{Σπάνις} γὰρ ἡμᾶς, ὡς ὁρᾶτε, κατειλήφει τῶν ἐδωδίμων. Διὸ δὴ σχεδιάζω τὴν πανδαισίαν, εἰ καὶ μὴ πολυτελῶς, μηδὲ ἀξίως τῆς κεκληκυίας, ἀλλά γε τὴν πεῖναν ἀναγκαίως δυναμένην παραμυθήσασθαι. Οὐ γὰρ αὕτη τῶν ἔγκωμίων προσδεὴς τῶν παρ᾿ ἡμῶν, ἀλλ᾿ ἡμεῖς τῆς παρ᾿ αὐτῆς δόξης ἐπιδεεῖς. Τὸ γὰρ δεδοξασμένον πῶς δοξασθήσεται;\footnote{ add. Πῶς ὁ ἥλιος λαμπρυνθήσεται;} Ἡ πηγὴ τοῦ φωτὸς, πῶς φωτισθήσεται; Ἀλλ᾿ ἡμῖν αὐτοῖς, δι᾿ ὧν δρῶμεν, πλέκομεν στέφανον. Ζῶ γὰρ ἐγώ, λέγει Κύριος, καὶ τοὺς δοξάζοντάς με δοξάσω. \\

βʹ. Δεῦτε, πάντες νοερῶς ᾧ ἡ δόξα καὶ τὸ κράτος, σὺν τῷ ἀνάρχῳ Πατρί, καὶ τῷ παναγίῳ καὶ ζωοποιῷ Πνεύματι, νῦν, καὶ ἀεὶ, καὶ εἰς τοὺς σύμπαντας καὶ ἀτελευτήτους αἰῶ νας τῶν αἰώνων. Ἔθος ἐστὶ ἐμπορευόμενος. \\
Σπάνη γὰρ ἡμᾶς, ὡς ὁρᾶτε, κατειλήφει τῶν ἐδωδίμων. Διὸ δὴ σχεδιάζω τὴν πανδαισίαν, εἰ καὶ μὴ πολυτελῶς, μηδὲ ἀξίως τῆς κεκληκυίας, ἀλλά γε τὴν πεῖναν ἀναγκαίως δυναμένην παραμυθήσασθαι. Οὐ γὰρ αὕτη τῶν ἔγκωμίων προσδεὴς τῶν παρ᾿ ἡμῶν, ἀλλ᾿ ἡμεῖς τῆς παρ᾿ αὐτῆς δόξης ἐπιδεεῖς. Τὸ γὰρ δεδοξασμένον πῶς δοξασθήσεται; Ἡ πηγὴ τοῦ φωτὸς, πῶς φωτισθήσεται; Ἀλλ᾿ ἡμῖν αὐτοῖς, δι᾿ ὧν δρῶμεν, πλέκομεν στέφανον. Ζῶ γὰρ ἐγώ, λέγει Κύριος, καὶ τοὺς δοξάζοντάς με δοξάσω. \\

γʹ. Δεῦτε, πάντες νοερῶς ᾧ ἡ δόξα καὶ τὸ κράτος, σὺν τῷ ἀνάρχῳ Πατρί, καὶ τῷ παναγίῳ καὶ ζωοποιῷ Πνεύματι, νῦν, καὶ ἀεὶ, καὶ εἰς τοὺς σύμπαντας καὶ ἀτελευτήτους αἰῶ νας τῶν αἰώνων. 

δʹ. Δεῦτε, πάντες νοερῶς ᾧ ἡ δόξα καὶ τὸ κράτος, σὺν τῷ ἀνάρχῳ Πατρί, καὶ τῷ παναγίῳ καὶ ζωοποιῷ Πνεύματι, νῦν, καὶ ἀεὶ, καὶ εἰς τοὺς σύμπαντας καὶ ἀτελευτήτους αἰῶ νας τῶν αἰώνων. Αμήν.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
  \pstart
   \eledsection{Dritte Predigt} 
  \pend
\pstart
\textbf{Dritte Predigt desselben über die Entschlafung der allheiligen Gottesgebärin.}\\

   1. Üblich ist, und geistliche Nachspeise. \\
   Denn, wie ihr seht, mangelt es uns an solcher Nahrung. Deshalb bereite ich eine Stärkung vor, die zwar weder sehr aufwendig noch des Anlasses würdig ist, aber hoffentlich den Hunger stillen kann. \\
   Nicht Sie braucht unser Lob, sondern wir sind es, die Ihre Herrlichkeit brauchen. Wie kann man denn die Herrlichkeit verherrlichen oder die Quelle des Lichts erleuchten? Wir erwerben uns damit einen Siegeskranz. \ledleftnote{1 Sam 2, 30}{„Ich lebe, sagt der Herr“; „und ich werde diejenigen verherrlichen, die mich verherrlichen“.} \\
   Es ist wirklich köstlich, Wein zu trinken und Brot zu essen. 
   \ledleftnote{Vgl. Ps 103, 15}{\textit{Das eine erfreut, das andere stärkt das Herz des Menschen}}. Doch was ist lieblicher als die Mutter meines Gottes? Sie hat meinen Geist gefangen und mein im Wachen und im Schlafen. Sie, des Logos Mutter, leitet mein Wort. den Sohn Gottes und unseren Gott, unsere Erlösung bewirkt hat. Ihm sei Ruhm und Majestät, mit dem ungeschaffenen Vater und dem allheiligen und lebensspendenden Geist, jetzt und für immer, durch alle Ewigkeiten. Amen.
   
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages} 
\Pages
\end{document}


Solution:


In the preamble:
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}


Before every first paragraph:
\noindent
There is certainly a more elegant solution.


